# how to access a local javascript var in greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, variables, greasemonkey, local

it's been an hour I'm going crazy with this problem.

There is a page, with a javascript function:

```
<script>
  function foofunction(foo){
      dosomething(foo);
    }
</script>
```

I have replaced this function with a greasemonkey script:

```
var scriptCode = new Array();

scriptCode.push('function foofunction(foo){    ');
scriptCode.push('    dosomething(foo);             ');
scriptCode.push('    myinjectedcode;               ');
scriptCode.push('}'                                 );

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.innerHTML = scriptCode.join('\n');
scriptCode.length = 0;

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
//here I have to access to foo value
```

This works.

Now I have to access to foo value in my greasemonkey script, how can I?

Comment: `function foofunction(var foo){` isn't valid JavaScript.  That should be `function foofunction(foo){`

Comment: yes you're right. I have made a mistake writing the code here, in the page the function is correct.

Comment: So, what does `myinjectedcode` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you making your JavaScript function inside a array?  I'm assuming `foofunction` is a global function, why don't you just make a function inside `window` (or `unsafeWindow`, I think, for Greasemonkey)?

```
unsafeWindow.foofunction = function(foo){
    dosomething(foo);
    //myinjectedcode;
}
```

`foo` is a local variable, so it only exists inside the `foofunction` function.  If you want access to it outside of that, you'd need to make it a global variable.

```
unsafeWindow.foofunction = function(foo){
    dosomething(foo);
    //myinjectedcode;
    unsafeWindow.myFoo = foo;
}
unsafeWindow.myFoo; // will be set to `foo`, but only after `fooFunction` is ran
```

Problem with that is, `myFoo` will only be set after `fooFunction` is ran, and there's no good way for you to wait until then.  I suggest making a "callback" function.

```
unsafeWindow.foofunction = function(foo){
    dosomething(foo);
    //myinjectedcode;
    unsafeWindow.myFooCallback(foo);
}
unsafeWindow.myFooCallback(foo){
    // this will be called with `foo` after `fooFunction` is ran.
}
```

But, this is kinda pointless as your injecting code into `fooFunction` anyway.

So, to answer your question, you cannot get the value of a local variable outside of the function.  Since you're injecting code anyway, why don't you just put all code relating to `foo` inside `fooFunction`?

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is keeping trace off the value in the process I recommend using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to debug this type off scripts, just put a breakpoint anywhere you want in your script and at the time it stops it will give you the current values off all the variables being use.